# How to store NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults and show results in TableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I want to save the Notifications which come from server in my application and also make a User Interface to give users the ability of chosing which Notification(message) to read. In a scheduled method my client controls for changes inside the server and the communication is in JSON format. I have parsed it and can see the results in `NSLog(@"....",..)` too. I also control the status of message from the server, if the status equals to 1 i will save the message and add a node to TableView.. Now, can anyone help me about how to transmit datas in `NSMutableArray` both to `NSUserDefaults` and TableView? I can Share code or JSON representation too if you want.. 
It will be better if you could explain with some code.. Thanks

I decided to share some of my code,

as i have writen under the code too, i want to display `NSMutableArray` in `UITableView`

```
    `-(IBAction)Accept:(id)sender
    {   userName=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:userNameField.text ];
        [userNameField setText:userName];
        NSUserDefaults *userNameDef= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userNameDef setObject:userName forKey:@"userNameKey"];
        password =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:passwordField.text];
        [passwordField setText:password];
        NSUserDefaults *passDef=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [passDef setObject:password forKey:@"passwordKey"];
        serverIP=[[NSString alloc] initWithString: serverField.text];
        [serverField setText:serverIP];
        NSUserDefaults *serverDef=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [serverDef setObject:serverIP forKey:@"serverIPKey"];
        [userNameDef synchronize];
        [serverDef synchronize];
        [passDef synchronize];


    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"BNTPRO "
                                                      message:@"Your User Informations are going to be sent to server. Do you accept?"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",  nil];
    [message show];
}



    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

        if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
        {
            if([userNameField.text isEqualToString:@""]|| [passwordField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [serverField.text length]<10) 
            {
                UIAlertView *message1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"BNTPRO "
                                                                   message:@"Your User Informations are not defined properly!"
                                                                  delegate:nil
                                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                         otherButtonTitles:  nil];

                [message1 show];


        [userNameField  resignFirstResponder];
            [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
            return;
        }
        //## GET code to here**
        NSString *str1=[@"?username=" stringByAppendingString:userNameField.text];
        NSString *str2=[@"&password=" stringByAppendingString:passwordField.text];
        NSString *str3=[str1 stringByAppendingString:str2];
        NSString *str4 =[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:serverField.text];


        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[str4 stringByAppendingString:[@"/ipad/login.php" stringByAppendingString:str3]]];
        NSLog(@"%@\n",url);
        //get the url to jsondata
        NSData *jSonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        if (jSonData!=nil) {
            NSError *error=nil;
            id result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jSonData options:
                       NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            if (error==nil) {
                NSDictionary *mess=[result objectForKey:@"message"];
                NSDictionary *messContent=[mess valueForKeyPath:@"message"];
                NSDictionary *messDate=[mess valueForKeyPath:@"date"];
                NSDictionary *messID=[mess valueForKeyPath:@"ID"];
                NSDictionary    *messStatus=[mess valueForKey:@"status"];

                NSLog(@"%@ *** Message %@ \n Message Content: %@ \n Mesage ID: %@ \n Message Date: %@\n \nilhancetin MessageSatus: %@", result, mess, messContent, messID,messDate,messStatus);
                NSString*key1=[ result objectForKey:@"key" ];

                NSString *s1=[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:serverField.text];
                NSString *s2=[s1 stringByAppendingString:@"/ipad/button.php"];
                NSURL *url2=[NSURL URLWithString:[s2 stringByAppendingString:[@"?key=" stringByAppendingString:key1]]];
                NSLog(@"\n%@\n",url2 );
                NSData *data2=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
                id result2=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data2 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

                NSMutableArray *mesID = [NSMutableArray array];//saving meesages to NSMutableArray
                NSMutableArray *status = [NSMutableArray array];    


                // i logged here and it saves  the data, now i want to display my data in table view
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save it in NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:yourArray forKey:@"theArray"];
```

get it from NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"theArray"];
```

setting values from an array to UITableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TheCell";
    UITableViewCell *_cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (_cell == nil) {
        _cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    _cell.textLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return _cell;
}
```

Hope it helps

**update**

don't have a Mac nearby at the moment, so my answer might be a bit sloppy.

In your header file don't forget to add UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, so it will look somewhat like that:

```
@interface yourController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ... some others if you need it ...> {
```

then in the implementation file(.m) you can just start typing

```
-tableview
```

and then use the autocompletion to get the methods that you need. You will most probably need these 3:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

depending on the needs of your app you might need more of them, but these 3 should be there.

For more info about UITableView please check that link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I will create new view after the response of GET, so where shall i place this code (or do i need to create a tableView in storybord before using this method?)?

Comment: @ilhançetin the cellForRowAtIndexPath method should already be present in your controller with UITableView. And the NSUserDefaults can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: I defined UITableView *tableView;and its property in my .h file and sysnthesized it, later used your method but nothing happened. 
I shall explain a little more, i have defined an action called Accept and when i press its button(call it) i save my login informations in my app with NSUserDefaults and at the same time send my values to Server, and receive JSON bac in that action.. I haven't created a TableView yet, now i have two questions..
 1) must i create a TableView?
 2) Where will i plase this code to make it run?
If the questions look stupid please forgive me

Comment: Thank You very much, i don't have my mac with me at the moment but as i see this will splve my problem. I will turn you back about the result.

Comment: You 've writen a very very clear answer but i indeed couldn't still handle.. How can i create tableview and place array on it can anyone please help me